# Pass Angular typeahead object result to another function in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

In this scenario I'm using the ui-bootstrap typeahead to capture an object from an external api.  Using the select callback I'm getting that object and have the results set in a separate function within my controller.

The issue is that I want to take those results and send them off to a separate api with a click function I already have set up.  My question is how do i get the results of the type-ahead into the click function to post?  The user flow is as follows.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Find A Game" 
           typeahead-on-select="setGames($item)" 
           ng-model="asyncSelected" 
           typeahead="test.name for test in getGames($viewValue)" 
           typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-min-length="3" 
           typeahead-wait-ms="500" typeahead-select-on-blur="true" 
           typeahead-no-results="noResults">
</div>


<div ng-show="noResults">
  No Results Found
</div>
<button ng-disabled="!asyncSelected.length" 
        ng-click="addtodb(asyncSelected)">Add To Database</button>
```

As you can see the label is set to the items name and this works fine.  When the user selects the name I then use **typeahead-on-select="setGames($item)"** to send off the entire object to its own funtion.  From there I want to take the object and pass it to another function that you can see within the button tags ng-click.  I currently have it passing the model, but what I really want is to pass the entire object within $item from the select event.  So far my controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('2o2pNgApp')
  .controller('GiantCtrl', function ($scope, $http, TermFactory, $window, SaveFactory) {

      $scope.getGames = function(val) {
        return $http.jsonp('http://www.example.com/api/search/?resources=game&api_key=s&format=jsonp&limit=5&json_callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {
          params: {
            query:  val
          }
        }).then(function(response){
          return response.data.results.map(function(item){
            return item;
          });
        });
      };

      $scope.setGames = function (site) {
        var newsite = site;
      };


      $scope.addtodb = function (asyncSelected, newsite) {
            TermFactory.get({name: asyncSelected}, function(data){
              var results = data.list;
              if (results === undefined || results.length === 0) {
          SaveFactory.save({vocabulary:'5', name:newsite.name, field_game_id:newsite.id}, function(data) {
              $window.alert('All Set, we saved '+asyncSelected+' into our database for you!')
          });
              } else {
                // do stuff
            });
      }

  });
```

No matter what I do I cant seem to pass the entire $item object into this click function to post all the info i need.

Comment: You are not passing the `$item` to `addtodb` - the `newsite` parameter is thus `undefined`. Are you not getting the `$item` in `setGames`?

Comment: I've tried it with just passing $item to addtodb as well without it working.  I am getting the $item from setGames function, but Im not sure how to then pass that into my addtodb function.

Comment: Well, `$item` is only available locally for `typeahead-on-select`... you can either assign it to some model within your controller, or, in fact, make the model of `typeahead` to be the item: `typeahead="test as test.name for test in getGames($viewValue)"`

Comment: Not sure how I assign it to another model.  For the second suggestion, this would work fine, but the problem is that then the dropdown and select just show [object] [object] as the results which makes it fairly unusable.

Comment: Method one did in fact work.  I was messing up the order and assigning it to the name and not the object.  Thanks New Dev!

Answer (score 0):

Via New Dev in Comments:

> $item is only available locally for typeahead-on-select... you can
>   either assign it to some model within your controller, or, in fact,
>   make the model of typeahead to be the item: typeahead="test as
>   test.name for test in getGames($viewValue)" –  New Dev